# Unity - Raycast distance doesn't change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, distance

I'm trying to detect the ground ahead of a cube that doens't have boxcollider or rigid body. I can detect it ok but the distance never changes. I can use very big number or very small ones that it still detects the ground at the same distance.

The debug lines are working fine and nothing is detected before the ground. Even trying raycast without distance keeps the detection at the same distance.
I tried some other variations of the method Raycast with the same results.

Here is my script:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
RaycastHit hitInfo;
Debug.DrawRay(pos, transform.forward * detectDistance, Color.green);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hitInfo, detectDistance)) {
       Debug.Log(hitInfo.transform.name);
       Debug.DrawRay(pos, transform.forward * detectDistance, Color.red);
}
```

Comment: What does hitInfo.distance return? How does it compare to detectDistance?

Comment: It always return 32 or less.
The cube is flying so it keeps getting smaller till 0.

Comment: Does the camera mess with the ray if it start's inside the camera's cone?

Comment: What value is failing to change? What change are you expecting to see in that value?

Comment: The detectDistance is set to 300f and it doesn't detect the ground till 32.
Even if i try to use raycast without distance it cant only detect the ground at 32 or bellow.

Answer (score 2):

If your main goal is to calculate the distance between two GameObjects (cube and ground), the use of Raycast is not a must. You can follow this other approach:

```
Vector3 dist = Vector.distance(cube.transform.position, ground.transform.position);
Debug.Log(string.Format("Distance between {0} and {1} is: {2}", cube, ground, dist));
```

However if you want to keep with the Raycast, without having all the information about how is your scene and how are the gameObjects located, I can only recommend you to try the following things:

1- Calculate the direction of the Ray like this:

```
Vector3 direction = ( cube.transform.position - ground.transform.position ).normalized;
Ray ray = new Ray( cube.transform.position, direction );
```

2- Calculate the distance from hit:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(downRay, out hit)) {
   float distance = hit.distance;
}
```

3- And just in case calculate the distance from `void FixedUpdate()`

Comment: Your suggestion work as fine as all the other ones I found over the internet but the distance still smaller than it should be.
I think the problem is somewhere else, I used Sebastian Lague terrain generator and maybe the problem is over his code.
Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: I found the problem, my word is split in chunks and eat one of then only became available to be detect by the raycast after I move the character over it, after that I can go pretty far away and it works fine.
Now I have absolutely no idea how to make the chunks work before I move over it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the other terrain chunks wasn't generating the collider mesh till you get really close to it.
I did find a way to generate it far away.